WP - ACF & Custom Theme - How to display existing custom fields from other pages of my website?
I'm interested in reusing a custom field from one page on another page while preserving its style and structure. Essentially, I want to replicate a field from one ACF group to another, ensuring that it fits seamlessly into the layout and design of the target page within the custom theme.
The website in question was developed by a WordPress developer utilizing Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) and a custom theme.
The developer has structured the theme's code with separate templates for each page, defining the layout and design elements.
About us code
<?php
/* Template Name: Sobre */
global $url_tema, $link_blog, $nome_blog;
get_header();

$showposts = 21;
$paged = 1;
if( isset($_GET['pagina']) ):
    $paged = $_GET['pagina'];
    $offset = ($paged - 1) * $showposts;
endif;

?>
<main class="sobre-page">

    <div class="bannerTop bg">
        <div class="main">
            <h1><?php the_title() ?></h1>
        </div>
        <img src="<?php echo get_field('imagem_banner')['url'] ?>" class="bg">
    </div>

    <section class="section01">
        <div class="main">

            <div class="bannerSection">
                <div class="ctn">
                    <h3>Who We Are</h3>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="text"><?php echo get_field('texto_01') ?></div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <div class="ctnVideo mt-40">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="gallery">
                <?php
                    foreach (get_field('videos_01') as $key) {
                        $url = $key['video'];
                        parse_str( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $my_array_of_vars );
                        echo '<iframe width="560" class="item" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$my_array_of_vars['v'].'" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <section class="sectionTimeline">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="slider">
                <?php

                    foreach (get_field('timeline') as $key ) {
                        echo '<div class="_item">
                                <figure><img src="'.$key['imagem']['sizes']['medium'].'"></figure>
                                <div class="right">
                                    <div class="ctn">
                                        <strong>'.$key['titulo'].'</strong>
                                        <p>'.$key['texto'].'</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>';
                    }
                
                ?>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="bannerSection">
            <div class="ctn">
                <h3><?php echo get_field('titulo_topo_03') ?></h3>
            </div>
            <img src="<?php echo get_field('banner_topo_03')['url'] ?>" class="bg">
        </div>

        <img src="<?php echo get_field('mapa')['url'] ?>" class="map">

        <div class="column-01">
            <!-- <div class="left">
                <img src="<?php echo $url_tema ?>assets/images/pin.png" class="icon">
                <div class="list">
                    <p>Fortaleza/CE</p>
                    <p>Caucaia/CE</p>
                    <p>Parnaíba/PI</p>
                </div>
            </div> -->
            
            <div class="text"><?php echo get_field('texto_03') ?></div>
        </div>

        <div class="bannerSection">
            <div class="ctn">
                <h3><?php echo get_field('titulo_topo_04') ?></h3>
            </div>
            <img src="<?php echo get_field('banner_topo_04')['url'] ?>" class="bg">
        </div>

        <div class="column">
            <div class="text"><?php echo get_field('texto_04') ?></div>
        </div>


        <div class="bannerSection">
            <div class="ctn">
                <h3><?php echo get_field('titulo_topo_4_5') ?></h3>
            </div>
            <img src="<?php echo get_field('banner_topo_4_5')['url'] ?>" class="bg">
        </div>

        <div class="column">
            <div class="text"><?php echo get_field('texto_4_5') ?></div>
        </div>

        <div class="bannerSection">
            <div class="ctn">
                <h3><?php echo get_field('titulo_topo_05') ?></h3>
            </div>
            <img src="<?php echo get_field('banner_topo_05')['url'] ?>" class="bg">
        </div>

        <div class="listPoints">
            <?php

                foreach (get_field('lista_04') as $key ) {
                    echo '<div class="_item">
                            <div class="icon"></div>
                            <div class="text">'.$key['item'].'</div>
                        </div>';
                }
            ?>
        </div>

    </div>

</main>
<?php
get_footer();

Additionally, he created custom field groups for each page within ACF, using labels, names, and field types to organize the content.
Within the theme's code, the developer retrieves the values of each custom field from the respective ACF groups associated with each page and integrates them into the template files.
I've tried duplicating a field

If the data you're after is stored in a specific post, and you know or can retrieve the post ID, relevant ACF get_* / the_* calls support passing the post ID as an optional argument:
get_field($selector, [$post_id = false], [$format_value = true], [$escape_html = false]);
If your post ID would be 5, for example:
get_field('texto_01', 5); would return the ACF field value for texto_01 specifically for post ID 5.
If there is data / fields to reference across many pages, I would recommend looking at the ACF options page as a "global" store for options, using 'option' in the place of the $post_id parameter. If you are referencing a single post's fields from multiple pages, you could instead store that post's ID in a global options page and then reference that to retrieve its post ID, then using that in your custom field calls instead.

If you'd like to re-use the entire block of code for templating, you can instead look into using WordPress template parts to isolate the styled block of code, and then including that block across all templates you wish to use it in.
Again, if it's a specific post ID you want to reference fields from, you could either hard-code the post ID or set it as an ACF global option and reference that option.
